# Using multiple variables in addClass/removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I can use one variable in addClass/removeClass

html:

```
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>and</p>
<p>Goodbye</p>
</body>
```

css:

```
p {
margin: 8px;
font-size: 16px;
}
.selected {
color: red;
}
.highlights {
background: yellow;
}
```

js:

```
var css1="selected";
var css2="highlights";

$( "p:last" ).addClass(css1);
```

I want use css1 and css2 variables in addClass method. I tried these:

```
$( "p:last" ).addClass(css1 css2);
$( "p:last" ).addClass("css1 css2");
```

They don't work.

If I use this:

```
var css3="selected highlights"
$( "p:last" ).addClass(css3);
```

it works

But how can I use css1 and css2 variables in addClass method ?

You can try on http://jsfiddle.net/hasyo1qm/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
$( "p:last" ).addClass(css1+" "+ css2);
```

Both class names need a **space** between them, so using concatenation we have to add a space between them, otherwise it will not behave right.

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/hasyo1qm/2/

Answer (score 4):

As noted elsewhere, you need to create a white-space separated string from your variables; one means (as shown):

```
$( "p:last" ).addClass(css1 + ' ' + css2);
```

Another alternative, however, which is slightly easier to type, is to use `Array.prototype.join()`:

```
$( "p:last" ).addClass([css1, css2].join(' '));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hasyo1qm/3/).

This, realistically, only becomes easier when you have more than two, or three, classes to concatenate.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: With `.join()` seems to be the nicest solution for me.

Comment: @algorhythm: it'd be my preference too, but with a list of only two classes it's actually slightly *less* efficient to use `join()`, with regards to typing.

Comment: nice way to do the task +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_(.2B)) your variables:

```
$( "p:last" ).addClass(css1 + ' ' + css2);
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hasyo1qm/1/)

Comment: Actually you should say something like *"You need to space separate your variables"*. simply concatenating the variables as it is will not help..

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way is to call `addClass` multiple times but in one line:

```
 $('p:last').addClass(css1).addClass(css2);
```

Comment: @TJ You are right. It's really useless ^^ I deleted it asap

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var css1 = " selected "; // added space before and after text in string
var css2 = " highlights "; // added space before and after text in string

$( "p:last" ).addClass(css1 + css2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hasyo1qm/4/